# C++ gcc function template overload compiler issue

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I have a class that has a couple of member functions defined as so:

```
template <class T> void query(std::vector<T>& retVec, ... rest of params)
{
  // get raw results
  DBCursor results = ...;

  // convert results
  this->fillVector(retVec, results);
}
```

Where fillVector() has a non-templatized version and a templatized overload:

```
void fillVector(std::vector<RawQueryType>& retVec, const DBCursor& results);

template <class T>
void fillVector(std::vector<T>& retVec, const DBCursor& results);
```

I had a bug in the *non-templatized* fillVector implementation, but a lot of code using the *templatized* overload. My thought was that although the fix to the non-template fillVector would require a lot of recompiling, the resulting .so shared library files would still be the same for everything using the templatized version. After recompiling what I'm observing is that library files are actually different.

So my question is, was this the correct assumption? If not, then why not?
If yes, then that means I'm probably calling the non-templatized version somewhere I didn't think I was?

Compiler is g++ 4.8.1

Comment: .so shared library files, on a red hat linux system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binaries are different because you changed the code. Your *non-templatized* function is there although it is not used/called in your code.

You can list symbols in your binary using this command:

```
nm -anC <binary> | grep fillVector
```

You should see one symbol for non-template and one symbol for each different use of template function. For more info see [this guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257589/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part) (especially template instantiation)

Comment: So should I expect to see a symbol entry for both fillVectors?

Comment: @mike: You should expect one for the nontemplate, and _many_ for the template version.

Comment: Okay, I can agree with this answer I was hoping for a cooler obscure c++ standard reasoning :). But just as an FYI too, when I run the command above, I do not see an entry for the non-templatized version